# Weka: How to remove instances with missing values

Tags: filter, weka

I'm using the Weka application and using a CVS file, I need to remove the instances with missing values. I tried to use the multi filter and use the removevalues filter, but I think I am doing it wrong since it filters ALL my instances. How do I do this right exactly?

Comment: Is it possible that all of your instances have at least one missing value?

Answer (score 3):

To remove instances with missing values from a few attributes you can use `weka.filters.unsupervised.instance.SubsetByExpression` and use an expression such as

```
not ismissing(ATT5)
```

to remove instances with missing values in the attribute with index 5, or

```
not (ismissing(ATT5) or ismissing(ATT8))
```

to remove instances with missing values in attributes 5 or 8, and so on.

If you were trying to use the `RemoveWithValues` filter, it can be done this way but you need to clear the `nominalIndices` field (removing the `-L` argument from the filter command) and set a `splitPoint` value more negative than the minimum value of the attribute being filtered. Otherwise this filter will match any instance whose value matches *any* of these conditions.

I can't see any obvious way of removing instances that have missing values in *any* attribute, other than building an expression for `SubsetByExpression` that checks all of them one by one.